# Bash Script Wind Chill using getopt and bc

Tags: bash, bc, getopts

I am now getting the correct output, however it is not scaling to only 3 places.  Anyone know how to do that?

```
function windchill {
    to=32
    v=10
    vel=`echo 'e(l('$v')*0.16)' | bc -l`
    w=$(echo "scale=3; $vel" | bc -l)
    twc=`echo "35.74 + (0.6215 * $to) - (35.75 * $w) + (0.4275 * $to * $w)" | bc`
    echo ''
    echo 'Windchill Calculator'
    echo 'Outside Air Temperature (F): '"$to"
    echo 'Wind Speed: '"$v"
    echo 'Wind-Chill (F): '"$twc"
    echo ''
    exit
}
```

I am getting the correct $tf and $v the $wc is my problem.  Using a calculator I get the correct answer just not in my bash file.  The problem is my $w is coming back as a 1 not 1.4454.

Comment: I don't quite nee why you call `windchill` inside the option parsing loop, ofter setting `speed` and `temp`. Wouldn't you want to set all parameters and then call `windchill` _after_ the loop?

Comment: I was under the impression that the shift means it would check the first one and then shift to the next one.  I completely guessing on how to do this.  My professor gave me a web site and said figure it out.  https://linuxaria.com/howto/parse-options-in-your-bash-script-with-getopt this is what he gave us as a reference

Comment: That other code that you previously showed could warrant another question. You did some odd things with command line parsing there that should be straightened out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(note that this answer was written for the question as originally posed, which included computing `v^0.16` in `bc`)

In `bc`, the `^` operator is *integer* exponentiation, so you're actually raising `v` to the 0 power, not 0.16. You can make use of logarithms to compute general exponents though: instead of `x^y`, you can use `e(y*l(x))`.  So here, instead of `v^0.16`, you'll want `e(0.16*l(v))`.

Note that this requires the `-l` switch to `bc` to include the standard math library. If you want a particular level of precision, you'll need to use the `scale` parameter of `bc`, which defaults to 20 when the `-l` switch is in use.

Comment: okay thanks for the help I got this to work however I need it only the the 3rd digit after the decimal


vel=`echo 'e(l('$v')*0.16)' | bc -l`

Comment: That's what `scale` is for

Comment: I have tried and I am still getting a long output, maybe I am not inputting it correctly.    w=$(echo "scale=3; $vel" | bc -l)  and my output is 1.44543977074592751192

Comment: `w=$(echo "scale=3; e(0.16 * l($v))" | bc -l)` works for me, at least for setting `w` correctly

Comment: I got it working thank you. for the help Fox